# ::after element not working in my React component - React 3D portfolio project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, three.js, mern

I'm working on a portfolio project by LamaDev (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qALsVa-V9qo&t=2334s&ab_channel=LamaDev). Around timestamp 36:40 he creates this ::after selector which doesn't work for me, although the rest of the listItem works. How do i debug? I see that no code in the ::after pseudo, even if I try text or background color

Github Link: https://shorturl.at/euzY6

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
// import './stylesheets/worksStyles.css'
const data = [
  'Web Development',
  'Data Science',
  'DevOps',
  'Low Code Platforms',
  'Automation',
];

const Section = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Left = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const List = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
`;

const ListItem = styled.li`
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  position: relative;
  ::after {
    content: "${(props) => props.text}";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    ::after {
      color: rebeccapurple;
    }
  }
`;

const Right = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
`;

const Works = () => {
  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        <Left>
          <List>
            {data.map((item) => (
              <ListItem key={item} text={item}>
                {item}
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Left>
        <Right></Right>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default Works;
```

I see that no code in the ::after pseudo works, even if I try text or background color

Answer (score 0):

### there is an error for setting the `::after` style

> just need to change the `::after` to `&::after`

```js
const ListItem = styled.li`
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    content: "${(props) => props.text}";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    &::after {
      color: rebeccapurple;
    }
  }
`;
```

> screenshot

[image]